# Javascript Scope undefined

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a problem with the online document of the website of jquery about javascript scope.There are codes;

```
(function() {

var baz = 1;

var bim = function() {
    console.log( baz );
};

bar = function() {
    console.log( baz );
};

})();
```

And says:

```
console.log( baz ); // baz is not defined outside of the function
```

the thing that I don't understand is that even though `baz` is defined, why `console.log(baz)` is undefined. Because I think the scope is the same. Did I miss something?

Comment: may you can take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Inside an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) the variable scope is *private* and for solely use inside your function scope.

Comment: Try with `window.baz = 1;` http://jsbin.com/OcifoKo/1/edit

Comment: i don't think the question is really about how to make the variable accessible outside of the functional scope.. using window.baz will just pollute the global scope.. The example should really mean that although you can't do console.log outside of the IIFE, you can call bar, which is able to reference baz, because bar is also defined in the same scope.

Comment: Any variable declared with `var` is only accessible inside the function it was defined in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the thing that I don't understand is that even though baz is defined, why console.log(baz) is undefined

It's undefined cause it's range is restricted (*private*) to the IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) scope.

If you chain your variable to the Window object, it'll be accessible globally.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OcifoKo/3/edit)**

```
(function() {

  window.baz = 1; // Global
  var pub    = 2; // private

  var bim = function() {
    console.log( baz );
  };

  var bar = function() {
    console.log( pub ); 
  };

  bim(); // 1 //////////
  bar(); // 2 //////////

})(); 


console.log( baz ); // 1 //////////
console.log( pub ); // Ref.Error //
```

Answer (score 5):

The trap is the `IIFE` - immediate invoked function expressions which creates their own scope.

JS is using **function** scope

So `baz` is *not* defined outside that IIFE.

```
change this to :

(function() {

 window.baz = 1;     <----

var bim = function() {
    console.log( baz );
};

bar = function() {
    console.log( baz );
};

})();
```

And it will work.

p.s.

This is how jQuery attach ( when they finish with bla bla..) the $ /jQuery to the window. ( only that the window.$ is at its last lines).

Comment: thank you I missed immediate invoked function expressions.I get it now thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

May be you are under "strict mode" ? In Chrome console everything is right. Calling of "baz" write 1 .

jsfiddle to check `jsfiddle.net/Yjq2v/`

Comment: He's running `console.log( baz );` outside the IIFE scope